# Localhost Permissions denied after upgrade to Mavericks

Tags: permissions, localhost, osx-mavericks

Upgraded to Mavericks and edited httpd.conf to enable php and virtual hosts. That's the only change made. Now when I try to access localhost I get the error: **Forbidden - you don't have permission to access xxxxx**

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem results from php not being executed any more, try to call e.g. the index.php directly and you will very likely see the sourcecode of your file.

go to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and uncomment:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

you have to restart your apache afterwards, so execute on command line:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps made it work for me:

1. Add an error_log path to your misbehaving vhost entries, so you can
   track the problem more closely

   ```
   <VirtualHost *>
    ...
    ErrorLog "/accessible/path/to/error_log"
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Restore all your previous apache settings, to be found at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous
3. Make sure your chmod and chown rights are up to date
4. Alter documentRoot settings if necessery (adding + did the trick for me)

   ```
       <Directory "/path/to/webroot">
           Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
       </Directory>
   ```
5. Optionally, add following entry to your .htaccess file

   ```
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
   ```

*Extra hint*

Incase you are using php, restore your ini file by copying php.ini-5.2-previous to php.ini

```
$ cd /private/etc/
$ sudo cp php.ini-5.2-previous php.ini
```

Sources

- http://brianflove.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-and-apache/
- http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/
- [Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901993/options-followsymlinks-or-symlinksifownermatch-is-off)