# "Error in exception handler" seen on fresh install

Tags: php, nginx, laravel

Just installed by the spec of the doc's larval. I am running on Ubuntu with Nginx as my server. Once I got it installed all I see is a white page and nothing else other than the words

> Error in exception handler

In my actual error logs I see

> Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/vhosts/dir/dir/dir/dir.com/public/index.pl

**note**: that I replaced the dir path here, with dir/dir/dir/dir...

Neither of which lead me to any conclusive examples of how to fix it or trouble shoot it. Soo. I am coming here hoping someone can help me solve this so I can attempt to use Laravel

Comment: [This answer will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17201624/741747).

Comment: might.. if Nginx supported `.htaccess` I'm sure I could find a way to convert most of those rules to be friendly with Nginx, but I'm trying to avoid a hackish approach, and would prefer something if at all possible organic to Nginx, I do thank you though, that will likely help those who are using Apache

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I am sure this will not answer everyones question to this problem, nor is it a solution I am fully happy with. I will have to research my server a little more for a better answer.

All in all what I ended up finding out through some digging is a particular directory needed to have write access. So for me to do that with my current server settings was to

```
sudo chmod -R guo+w app/storage
```

from the command line to allow global write privileges to the `app/storage` directory

Comment: Woah, I have been digging this error for hours. I had the same issue on fresh Laravel installation. Thanks!

Comment: this answer is the answer to about a million people's problems. made its way into the docs eventually. found it here first. big ups.

Answer (score 0):

I generally the artisan serve with sudo. This will give artisan all the permissions it needs and won't make any security troubles as well.

so instead starting artisan serve with:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

try using:

```
$ sudo php artisan serve
```

thus you wont have to make any permission changes