# index.php codeigniter not loaded in virtual host apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I have apache2 that installed in ubuntu 14.04 . My plan is to put my codeigniter application's folder that called "tresnamuda". I know the default virtual host in ubuntu is /var/www/. So, I put the "tresnamuda" into /var/www/tresnamuda.

But, it gives me blank page. When I right clik on internet browser, the contains of index.php is loaded like this :

```
<?php

/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
*---------------------------------------------------------------
*
* You can load different configurations depending on your
* current environment. Setting the environment also influences
* things like logging and error reporting...........
```

I dont know where is the error, coz in /var/www/tresnamuda/.htaccess contains code like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /tresnamuda/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In apache conf on /etc/apache2/sites-available/tresnamuda.com.conf, I write like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin itjkt@tresnamuda.co.id
   ServerName 192.168.5.222
   ServerAlias http://192.168.5.222
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tresnamuda
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I write like this :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All   
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have try a lot of times. I use `sudo a2ensite tresnamuda.com.conf`
, i t still blank page when I access on internet broswer like this : http://192.168.5.222.

Please, any advice it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like PHP isn't installed, or that at least PHP isn't configured with Apache.  Do PHP files in the root folder run correctly?

If not, you'll need to install PHP

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Then, once that's done, restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If PHP is installed, I've found a resource on [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) which might help.  The relevant part, i think, would be:

> It may also be useful to add php to the directory index, to serve the
>   relevant php index files:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

> Add index.php to the beginning of index files. The page should now look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
           DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with further things to try.  It's an odd issue as I've never had this trouble setting up PHP and Apache on Ubuntu

Comment: OMG, I still get this error " AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions : /var/www/tresnamuda/"

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901993/options-followsymlinks-or-symlinksifownermatch-is-off to see if it helps this latest issue